# What is stopping my theme from using a file that uses a suggested file name?

Tags: 7, theming

I needed to modify a module's .tpl file and so copied it, renamed it to something suggested by Theme Debug's file suggestions.

Eg when I run `drush theme_debug` I see:

```
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * image-resp-item--f6.tpl.php
   x image-resp-item.tpl.php
-->
```

So I rename my new file `image-resp-item--f6.tpl.php` and place it in my site's theme.

I clear cache and rebuild the theme registry but to no affect - the site still uses the original .tpl.

To experiment, I change my new .tpl's name to match the old one (remove `--f6`). This works - I see my new code appear on the site.

Why is my site (or theme?) not wanting to use the suggested file name?

Answer (score 0):

Your can either use hook_preprocess_page or if you don't want to code use something like [context](https://www.drupal.org/project/context) module. You can add a new context to select theme template based on your requirement.

Comment: So I would have to write a code to include each modified .tpl file? I thought  that was the point of theme suggestions - to automate this?